# Recurrence relation for the coefficients of the polynomial $p_n(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-i)$

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, matlab, products

Let's consider the polynomials

$$ p_n(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n,i}x^i$$.

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $n=1$, then $p_1(x) = x$ and $a_{1,1} = 1$.

Since I know that:

$$p_{n+1}(x) = p_n(x)(x-n)$$

then I can deduce the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{n+1,i}x^i & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n,i}x^i(x-n) = \\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n,i}x^{i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n} na_{n,i}x^i = \\
& = & \sum_{i=2}^{n+1} a_{n,i-1}x^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n} na_{n,i}x^i = \\
& = & a_{n,n}x^{n+1} + \sum_{i=2}^{n} (a_{n,i-1}-na_{n,i})x^i -na_{n,1}x.\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Then I get this recurrence relation for the coefficients $a$:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcll}
a_{n+1,n+1} & = & a_{n,n} & \\
a_{n+1,i} & = & a_{n,i-1}-na_{n,i} &~\forall i \in \{2, \ldots, n\}, ~\forall n \geq 2 \\
a_{n+1,1} & = & -na_{n,1} & \\
a_{1,1} & = & 1 &
\end{array}\right.$$

Is this right? I wrote a Matlab code for this but it seems to work only up to $n=19$!!! I mean, I produce two polynomials, one using the formula

$$p_n(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-i)$$

and one using the recurrence relation I found. When $n=20$, the difference between the two polynomial is not $0$. Is my maths correct or I have to review my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $a_{n,i}$ are  the Stirling numbers of the first kind

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I checked out it and I verified that $a_{n,i}$ I wrote are the signed Stirling number of the 1st kind. So, my maths is ok, right?

Comment: I further investigated. The code has some numerical problem when high numbers are evaluated.